# symfony2 demo application error

Tags: php, symfony

I installed the new Symfony demo application.

When I browse the app it shows me an exception !

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Undefined offset: 1") in blog/index.html.twig at line 22.
500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Runtime
1 linked Exception: ContextErrorException »
```

When i checked the `index.html.twig` I found this line of code

```
{{ show_source_code(_self) }}
```

Anyone can help ?

Comment: What is 'show_source_code' ? A custom twig extension ? If yes, Can you share the code behind ?

Comment: What demo app is? Can you provide the link from you download it? Are you navigating the dev environment?

Comment: With the new symfony installer just type php symfony demo in cmd